# how can I add my NSMutableArray into sqlite3 database?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I am new in iphone development, and I have made a simple application for restaurant order application, I have two NSMutableArray, one containing the names of different restaurants, and second is storing the price of items that are ordered, 
I display them into UITable, but now I want to save them in sqlite3 database, how can I do that, by easy way,,,,

I have created a database file, use terminal of Mac, and one more thing that I have using simulator, not the iphone for now,,,,

any suggestion????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use Core Data if you want you work with databases on iPhone OS.

This tutorial should match your app quite well: [iPhone Core Data: Your First Steps](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)

Please ask if any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of [tutorials](http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) for using sqlite with iphone. Its not a matter of simulator or device. It will work fine with simulator also.

Create your db structure properly and work based on this tutorials.